# Converting value of an Eval from int to string

Tags: c#, asp.net, eval

I have an integer stored in my database that I need to convert string.

This is my attempt at the Eval:

```
<%# ChangeSalaryType(Eval("SalaryType")) %>
```

This is my attempt at the function:

```
public static string ChangeSalaryType(int salaryType)
{
    string salaryTime = string.Empty;

    if (salaryType == 1)
    {
        salaryTime = "per hour";
    }
    else if (salaryType == 2)
    {
        salaryTime = "per week";
    }
    else if (salaryType == 3)
    {
        salaryTime = "per annum";
    }
    return salaryTime;
}
```

But I am getting these errors:

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'int'   
Error   2   The best overloaded method match for 'controls_allPlacements.ChangeSalaryType(int)' has some invalid arguments   
Error   4   The best overloaded method match for 'controls_allPlacements.ChangeSalaryType(int)' has some invalid arguments
```

I have used "SalaryType" in the Eval as that is the parameter that has the information from the database in. I'm not completetly sure what I am doing wrong..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Even though you know that the `SalaryType` field will be an `int` in your aspx it will be cast as `object` after the Eval().  Do an explicit cast like so:

```
<%# ChangeSalaryType(Convert.ToInt32(Eval("SalaryType"))) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to convert to `int` on your *Eval* part;

```
Convert.ToInt32(Eval("SalaryType"))
```

`Eval` probably return `object` as a return type.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to send the DataItem on code behind, and there get the data as:

```
<%#RenderSalaryType(Container.DataItem)%>
```

and on code behind

```
protected string RenderSalaryType(object oItem)
{
    int salaryType = (int)DataBinder.Eval(oItem, "SalaryType");

    // rest of your code
}
```