# Passing multiple parameters to a function through an Eval

Tags: c#, asp.net, eval

I am tyring to pass two values to a function through an Eval.

My function:

```
public static string ValidateSalary(int salaryFrom, int salaryTo)
{
    string salary = string.Empty;

    if (salaryFrom == salaryTo)
    {
        salary = "£" + salaryFrom.ToString();
    }
    else 
    {
        salary = "£" + salaryFrom.ToString() + " - £" + salaryTo.ToString();
    }
    return salary;
}
```

My Eval attempt:

```
<%# ValidateSalary(Eval("SalaryFrom", "SalaryTo")) %>
```

My error:

```
Error   5   No overload for method 'ValidateSalary' takes 1 arguments
```

I've tried multiple ways of formatting it and I can't figure it out!

Comment: `<%# ValidateSalary(Eval("SalaryFrom"), Eval("SalaryTo")) %>`

Comment: I have tried that @caerolus and I get even more erros.

Comment: @lauw0203 If you see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15864175/159270 on your previous question, you can notice that you can get any parametre on code behind, just by passing the DataItem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Pass Like this...

```
<%# ValidateSalary(Convert.ToInt32(Eval("SalaryFrom")),Convert.ToInt32(Eval("SalaryTo"))) %>
```

Comment: Thanks @amit-singh, I tried using convert on one but not the other, so I was still getting the error!

Answer (score 1):

By sending the DataItem on code behind, you can get any parameter as:

```
<%#RenderSalaryType(Container.DataItem)%>
```

and on code behind

```
protected string RenderSalaryType(object oItem)
{
    int salaryType = (int)DataBinder.Eval(oItem, "SalaryType");
    string salaryFrom = (int)DataBinder.Eval(oItem, "SalaryFrom").ToString();
    string salaryTo = (int)DataBinder.Eval(oItem, "SalaryTo").ToString();

    // rest of your code
}
```

Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/15864175/159270

Answer (score 0):

Use [Eval](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.databinder.eval%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) twice

```
<%# ValidateSalary(Convert.ToInt32(Eval("SalaryFrom")), Convert.ToInt32(Eval("SalaryTo")) %>
```