# Pass Eval Integer Into Function

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Aim: Pass a value, that is an integer in the SQL DB and return a text value

Issue: To get the value from Eval to the function I seem to have to put .tostring which makes is a string not a number. If I try with the below convert.toint32 no value is passed over. I have tried with .tostring on the end.

Checks: Without the Eval I get the number showing in the Grid and when use .tostring without a convert is passes the number through as as string then fails at the search as I can not get the string to become a number?!

I have looked at various forum discussions, not least [Converting value of an Eval from int to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15864001/converting-value-of-an-eval-from-int-to-string)

Code:

.aspx

```
  <%# RiskIDToText(Convert.ToInt32(Eval("RiskID")))%>
```

.aspx.vb

```
Public Function RiskIDToText(ByVal vRiskIDString As Integer) As Integer

        Dim vString As String = ""

        Dim sConnString As String = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SQL").ConnectionString
        Dim dsNames As SqlDataSource

        dsNames = New SqlDataSource
        dsNames.ConnectionString = sConnString
        Dim sSQL As String

        sSQL = "SELECT RiskCategories,RiskCatID FROM TblRisks_Categories WHERE RiskCatID =  '& vRiskIDString & '"
        dsNames.SelectCommand = sSQL

        For Each datarow As Data.DataRowView In dsNames.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty)

            vString = datarow("RiskCategories").ToString

        Next

        Return vString

    End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try changing your functoin declaration like this:

```
Public Function RiskIDToText(ByVal vRiskIDString As Integer) As String
      dim vRiskIDStr= cstr(vRiskIDString)  ''use vRiskIDStr in db query.
```

rest of the code remains same.

Comment: If I put "as integer" no value comes though and if I put "as string"  I get - On the For Each line I get "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '& vRiskIDString & ' to data type int."

Comment: Changed Integer and String around and then it works. No need for the second line of code. Now the vString says it is the wrong type as it is a string... :-S

Comment: glad you did it. regards

Answer (score 0):

.aspx

```
   <%# RiskIDToText((Eval("RiskID")))%>
```

.aspx.vb

```
 Public Function RiskIDToText(ByVal vRiskIDString As String) As String

    Dim vString As String = ""

    Dim sConnString As String = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SQL").ConnectionString
    Dim dsNames As SqlDataSource

    dsNames = New SqlDataSource
    dsNames.ConnectionString = sConnString
    Dim sSQL As String

    sSQL = "SELECT RiskCategories,RiskCatID FROM TblRisks_Categories WHERE RiskCatID =  '" & vRiskIDString & "' "
    dsNames.SelectCommand = sSQL

    For Each datarow As Data.DataRowView In dsNames.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty)

        vString = datarow("RiskCategories").ToString

    Next

    Return vString

End Function
```